# Get corresponding 3D object coordinates/vertices from a window touch in OpenGL

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, 3d, projection

I setting up an OpenGL iOS project. I´m read a lot about the projection matrix an GluUnproject. I want to draw on an 3D model dynamically. Therefore I need the corresponding points from my window to the 3D object. 
From GluUnproject I get a ray through my 3D scene. After that I can find collision point with iterative algorithms (raytracing)...

Now the problems:

- How do I get the corresponding texture?
- How do I get the corresponding vertices/pixels?
- How can I write on that perspective texture/pixel?

Answer (score 1):

How do I get the corresponding texture?

Getting the texture should be easy enough if you are using an object based approach to the objects in your scene. Just store a reference to the texture file name in the class and then iterate through your scene objects in your raycasting method, grabbing the texture name when you get a match.

How do I get the corresponding vertices/pixels?

Again this should be easy if you have used an object based approach for your object drawing (i.e an instantiation of a custom object class for each object in the scene). Assuming all your scene objects are in an NSMutableArray, you can just iterate through the array until you find a match on the raycasted object.

How can I write on that perspective texture/pixel?

If you are looking at writing text on a new texture one way of doing this is to use the layer of a UILabel as a texture (e.g see below), but if you are looking at drawing on an existing texture this is much more difficult (and to be honest to be avoided).

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
    label.text = text;
    lLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(standLabel.bounds.size);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, height);

    CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // flip transform used to transform the coordinate system from origin for OpenGL.
    CGAffineTransform flipTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.f, height),
                                                              CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.f, -1.f));
    CGContextConcatCTM(myContext, flipTransform);

    CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, -1.0);

    [standLabel.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *layerImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Hey thank you for this answer. I want to draw in perspective on this 3D model. How can I get the translation and rotation from my object? How do I get the match? I am iterating along the ray, but I have vertices only!?